# Have any function to know that I click the keyboard delete button in the UITextView by Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

As my question title, I want to know the user click the delete button like following image.
Thanks.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

   if text == "" {
       print("Text is null")
   } 
}
```

[image: image here.]

Comment: What is the "delete button"?

Comment: I update the image. Thanks.

Comment: This condition(if text == "") is not getting true when you press backspace?

Comment: What's wrong with your code snippet? If you press the delete button on the keyboard your expression should be `true`.

Answer (score 5):

`UITextField` conforms to `UITextInput` protocol which in terms inherits from `UIKeyInput` protocol.
`UIKeyInput` protocol has `func deleteBackward()` function which is called when user press delete button on the keyboard.

Create a custom subclass that inherits from `UITextField` and do your work inside that function. May be notify your event handler through your custom delegate or something.

```
class YourCustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        // do your work here
    }

}
```

Remember to call `super.deleteBackward()` so that it will delete a single character or selected range of characters when user tap delete button. If you didn't call, the text wont change when user taps the delete button.

Answer (score 4):

Compare the count of characters of textField and result string after replacement

```
var txtBeforeUpdate:NSString = textField.text as NSString!

var txtAfterUpdate = txtAfterUpdate.replacingCharacters(in: range,     with: string) as NSString
```

Also the best way:

```
let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

if (isBackSpace == -92) {
     print("Backspace was pressed")
}
```

Comment: what if the `textField.text` is empty?

Comment: Moreover user can copy/paste